# Do you have to make a separate app to make a paid version?

Tags: ios, iad

I have an app and I want to know, if I want to provide a paid version that's ad free, do I have to make a totally separate app? Like one app that has ads, and then do  I have to completely remake the app without ads?

Comment: You *can*, but I wouldn't recommend it (I'm not sure, but I think I read somewhere that Apple no longer accepts two app versions that have minute differences such as removing ads). Instead, you should add an in-app purchase to your application to remove ads

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best practice is to make a full version of your app but limit the functionality. Then you provide in-app purchases to enable the functionality that was limited. You can do this all at once or in parts.

For example, a game where level 1 is free, levels 1-5 are $0.99, levels 1-10 are $1.99, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/):

Submitting several apps that are essentially the same ties up the App Review process and risks the rejection of your apps. Improve your review experience — and the experience of your future users — by thoughtfully combining your apps into one.